# How can I sync a spreadsheet from Google Sheets to Calendar with empty cells?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm new to Sheets scripts and can't sync to Google Calendar with empty rows. I ask you to guide me. No error is generated but it does not copy the data to Calendar. Before modifying it, it generated the dates in Calendar, returning the error (String, String, String). Obviously the script also stopped when it reached the empty rows. I attach the code. Thank you.

- function onOpen() {
- var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
- ui.createMenu('Calendari')
- ```
    .addItem('Crear Visites', 'Crearvisites')
  ```
- ```
    .addToUi(); }
  ```
- 
- 
- function Crearvisites() {
- var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
- var configCalendar = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Calendar");
- var calendarID = configCalendar.getRange("D2").getValue();
- var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
- var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:D500").getValues();
- 
- for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
- var slot = signups[x];
- var startTime = slot[0];
- var endTime = slot[1];
- var title= slot[2];
- if (title && startTime && endTime) {
- if (eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime).length == 0) {
- eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime);
- ```
      }
  ```
- ```
     }
  ```
- ```
  }
  ```

I tried the chat recommendations but it didn't work for me.